# page parameter cannot take a var for ForwardAction in Struts

Tags: jsp, struts, jstl, forward

I am trying to use ForwardAction in Struts to navigate from one jsp to another without construting a customized action class.

In the first jsp, I have some line like this

```
<html:link page="/mainFAQs.do">FAQS</html:link>
```

which works fine.

But when I tried to use some variable for the page parameter like this

```
<html:link page="<c:out value="${faqLink}"/>" >FAQS</html:link>
```

I got an error message like this

```
Unable to create an xml attribute from name [${faqLink}] value [/&gt;]
```

I tried to use `page="${faqLink}"` but then it is just parsed as a string of ${faqLink}

Does that mean the page parameter cannot take a var? Please help me out of that trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html:link page="${faqLink}" >FAQS</html:link>
```

It should work otherwise check if you declared on top:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
```